# Same filename in differen Django apps opens the same template

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Currently I create a Django Website. I created one app.

```
project
--app
----templates
------index.html
----url.py
----views.py
--project
----templates
------index.html
----url.py
----views.py
```

in both url.py i create the url-pattern `url(r'^', views.index, name="index"),` and the url.py file in project contains `url(r'^heatingControll/', include('heatingControll.urls')),`.

In both views I add the function :

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = {}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

As I understand, Django will opens the `index.html` from the `app/template` folder by run 127.0.0.1:8000/app, and by run 127.0.0.1:8000 the `index.html` from the `project/template`folder.

But it runs each time the `app/templates/index.html` file.

I strongly belive that it should be possible to use the same directory name in serveral apps.

What could be my problem?

Comment: you are supposed to make a folder inside the templates folder with the name of your app. In this folder you put the html templates. In the view you call them `appName/index.html`. see this or any other link you can find on that topic http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not how it works. You need to namespace the templates, even if they're inside an app.

```
--app
----templates
------app
--------index.html
```

or, just keep the single project-level templates file, but still use namespaces:

```
--project
----templates
------index.html
------app
--------index.html
```

Either way, you now reference the template as `"app/index.html"`.

Note, you should really use the `render` shortcut:

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

Also note, it's not usual to have a project-level views.py. Normally that would be inside an app.